# How to read a line that contains non-string command inside a file via bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

Below is a snapshot of a file called ".bashrc":

[image]

I'm beginner in bash and What i'm trying to do in bash is to check if the last two lines inside the file exist and correctly written like for example  :

```
if [ export PATH=/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin:$PATH ]
then
   echo "found system variable lines"
else
   echo "systemvariables do not exists, please insert it in .bashrc"
fi
```

However, this doesn't seem to be trivial since the tow lines to be shared are not pure string lines.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear (to me, at least) what you're trying to do. If you want to check whether the `PATH` contains a particular string (for example, `/opt/ads2x`), you can test it in `bash` by `if [[ $PATH = */opt/ads2x* ]]; then echo "found"; else echo "not found"; fi`. Ditto for the other variable.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin thanks for the comment. the line `export PATH=/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin:$PATH` as whole must be added manually to the .bachrc file (mostly at the end of the file). and then my bash script serves as a verification method and must simply check if it exists

Comment: You might interest yourself in some automation tools like  ansible with it's `lineinfile` module. Please do not post images of text. Please post text as text.

Comment: @k.jbaili Then why not `if grep -Fxq 'export PATH=/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin:$PATH' ~/.bashrc; then echo "found"; else echo "not found"; fi` ?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin. Thanks that works

Comment: @k.jbaili Note that there are caveats with this solution. For instance, there may be a line (for example,  `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`) 
 following the `export PATH=/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin:$PATH` line in `.bashrc`, which invalidates this assignment. So that "solution" doesn't guarantee that `PATH` will contain the required directory even if the `grep` test succeeds.

Comment: What do you mean by "pure string lines"?  `.bashrc` is a text file.  Everything in it is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep` to find stuff in file contents.

```
# if file .bashrc contains the line exactly export PATH=....
if grep -Fxq 'export PATH=/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin:$PATH' .bashrc ; then
   echo "found system variable lines"
else
   echo "systemvariables do not exists, please insert it in .bashrc"
fi
```

Read `man grep` and decide if you want or not the `-F` and `-x` options in grep. For sure research and learn regex - I recommend regex crosswords available on the net. Research also difference between single quoting and double quoting in shell. Remember to check scripts with http://shellcheck.net